# How do I find all recrods with timestamp more than 120 days ago

Tags: sql, db2

I need a query to find all records with a timestamp greater than 120 days.

```
select * from table where timestamp > 120 days
```

How would i compare the timestamp to 120 days? Ive only compared dates which seems to be a lot easier.

Comment: what's your table structure? Please share.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want more than 120 days AGO.  That would:

```
where timestamp < current_date - interval 120 day
```

If you want the most recent 120 days worth of data reverse the comparison.

Comment: curdate() and interval 120 days is not working. 
Using db2 databases so CURRENT_DATE works but not INTERVAL

Comment: @OpenMeyends . . . That should be "day", not "days".

Comment: @OpenMeyends . . . Why does your question have a MySQL tag if that is not the database you are using?

Comment: @OpenMeyends thats why it is important to tag your question with correct database. We give answers looking at the database that you are using. No worries!! You got your answer. but from next time onwards, keep that in mind. We are ready to help you at earliest. Keep coding and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks everyone., made that mistake. although the answer below does still does not work

Answer (score 0):

If your table name is "table_name" and timestamp column is "date_col" then you can use below query:

```
select * from table_name where date_col > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 120 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with Db2, and if I got you correctly, you want rows older than 120 days.

So syntax would be:

```
select * from table where timestamp < (current date - 120 days)
```

Sample:

```
DDATE
----------
2020-12-01
2020-11-01
2020-10-01
2020-09-01

  4 record(s) selected.
```

the query would return only..

```
DDATE
----------
2020-09-01

  1 record(s) selected.
```